# Adjusting custom grid intervals based on map scale for PMF published from ArcMap for ArcReader

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.0, grids-graticules, arcgis-publisher, arcreader

I am preparing a pmf which includes a custom grid overlay. To clarify: a custom grid overlay is marginalia, not a feature class with geometry (so a scale dependecy inside a layer won't work).  The final user, in ArcReader, will interact with this map at any scale, zooming in and out as they please.  So far, the grid intervals stay the same, regardless of scale, which results in too many grid values at small scales and too few grid values at large scales.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In the old days, before automatic graticules were possible, we dealt with this by creating graticule feature classes (well, coverages, shapefiles and mapinfo tables then) using the [fishnet](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000002q000000) command. There is no means to control labels at the neatline but it handles the grid part nicely.

Make sure to create the grids in geographic lat-long coordinate system and then [densify](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001v00000003000000.htm) them so that when used in a projected space like Albers or UTM they curve nicely (else only the corners are accurate).